# redirect exec command output in tcl

Tags: scripting, tcl

Can you pls let me know how to avoid the console output print after executing the below command. The `exec` output anyway is put in `buf`, so I do not want the command to print on console.

```
(bin) 49 % set buf "[exec cmd /c  dir c:\\Program\ files\ (x86)\\WinPcap\\]"
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is x8

Directory of c:\Program files (x86)\WinPcap

04/17/2018  12:50 PM    <DIR>          .
04/17/2018  12:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/17/2018  12:50 PM               422 install.log
03/01/2013  07:18 AM           118,520 rpcapd.exe
04/17/2018  12:50 PM           121,106 Uninstall.exe
           3 File(s)        240,048 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  63,677,669,376 bytes free
(bin) 50 %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter writes, check out a previous answer. To get you going:

```
% set x [exec ls]; list
```